# Show that the functor $H: J \rightarrow \text{Ab}$ sending each $X$ to the free abelian group generated by the set $X$ is not continuous.

Tags: category-theory

> Show that the functor $H: J \rightarrow \text{Ab}$ sending each $X$ to the free abelian group generated by the set $X$ is not continuous.

I start by assuming that $H$ is continuous and therefore there's a universal cone $v : D \dot \rightarrow F$ for some $F: J \rightarrow \text{Set}$ where $J$ is small.  Let $HY = \Bbb Z^{|Y|}$ for any set $Y$.

Since I'm assuming that $H$ is continuous, that means $Hv_j : \Bbb Z^{|D|} \dot \rightarrow  \Bbb Z^{|F_j|}$ is a limiting cone.  So for any abelian group $A$ and cone $f_j : A \rightarrow \Bbb Z^{|F_j|}$ there should be a unique $h:A \rightarrow \Bbb Z^{|D_j|}$ such that $Hv \circ h = f$.

But I'm having trouble finding the contradiction to this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The functor $H$ should be $\mathsf{Set}\to \mathsf{Ab}$, I presume.

Comment: That's correct, I'll edit it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in sets, the product of a one element set with itself *any* amount of times is still a one element set. What happens for free abelian groups of rank $1$?

Comment: (In fact, a countably infinite direct product of free abelian groups of rank one is not free, so you're out of category to begin with.)

Comment: I see that $n$ products of a free abelian group of rank $1$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$, but I'm not quite sure what you're hinting at from here.

Comment: @OliverG That your functor be continuous means it commutes with limits. You just observed this is not the case.

Comment: Note that this is a consequence of the fact that the free abelian group of rank one is not a terminal object in the category of abelian groups, i.e. $H$ does not even preserve the terminal object.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm not sure I understand what specifically I've contradicted by showing this this.  It's my understanding that to commute with limits means $H$(limiting cone) is a limiting cone, what part did I contradict?

Comment: @OliverG No, you want $H$ to send universal cones to universal cones. The image of a cone is always a cone, by definition of a cone.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is there a difference between limiting cones and universal cones?  In Mac Lane's category theory he defines them as being the same thing.

Comment: @OliverG Same thing. Point being that $H$ does not preserve them.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Can you explain how I've shown they're not preserved?  I don't explicitly see what I've contradicted by showing that the product of $n$ rank $1$ free abelian groups is a free abelian group of rank $n$.

Comment: @OliverG You have that $ F(\ast\times\ast) = \mathbb Z$ which is different from $F(\ast)\times F(\ast) = \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Did you mean $H(* \times * ) = \Bbb Z$ and $H(*) \times H(*) = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$?  As $F: J \rightarrow \text{Set}$ is just an arbitrary functor and I don't understand how you would get $F(* \times *) =(\text{ the set }) \Bbb Z$ by objects $* \in J$ .

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What part of the definition of the continuity of $H$ requires that $H(* \times *)$ must equal $H(*) \times H(*)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72553/discussion-between-pedro-tamaroff-and-oliver-g).